# Limit which domains can access your js files with <script src=""> through .htaccess

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have unusual question.

There are some domains that shouldnt be allowed to read my js files that are on my hosting, but they do it anyway with

```
<script src="LINKTOMYFILES"></script>
```

I can do basic things with htaccess but no idea how to do this one.

Basically I have a list of domains that should be accessing my js files.

And I want to limit these files just to these domains.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using this: (I'm assuming you're using Apache 2.4)

```
<Files "file.js">
Require all denied
Require host example.com
Require host example2.com
</Files>
```

So this blocks access to `file.js` for everything, but allows access from the domains `example.com` and `example2.com`.

Comment: thanks but this code only blocks access to certain file. it doesnt let any domain access it no matter what i write in require host